# Trying to prove that an intersection of decreasing nest of non-empty closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be an empty set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Let $E_1 \supseteq E_2 \supseteq \dots \supseteq E_k \supseteq \dots$
>   be a decreasing nest of nonempty closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I
>   want to give an example to show it is possible for
>   $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$ to be empty.

But if $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed, doesn't that mean that each coordinate of $E = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ must be lying in some closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$? That is for each $x_k{\textrm{'}}s \in E$,  $a_1\leq x_1 \leq b_1$,  $a_2 \leq x_2 \leq b_2$, $\dots$, $a_n \leq x \leq b_n$?

If this is correct, then by the nest intervals theorem, $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$ will be some single point as each interval $[a_1,b_1], [a_2,b_2],\dots ,[a_n,b_n]$ become a single point. Hence, I will not be able to find an example of what is asked in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : What about $E_1=[1,+\infty[$, $E_2=[2,+\infty[,\dots$ ?

Comment: So if the question said the sets $E_k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ were closed *and* *bounded*, would my reasoning be valid? I forgot that closed set can be unbounded like you shown.

Comment: Exactly, that's precisely the point. There is a more general fact which says that a decreasing sequence of nonempty compact sets in a topological space is a nonempty compact set, and closed/bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are exactly compact sets.